# How to dictionary in this case with GAS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a newbie and non-native...

```
function fetch_json() {
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.ookami.me/v1/news/public?sport_id=1");
  var obj = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ecv2r3qBEuHWyP4XH7FkGktQ7YHqegd7CztRoARzKac");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("soccer");

  for (var n=0; n < 10; n++) {
    var news = json["news"][n];
    var a = news["id"];
    var b = news["title"];
    var c = news["summary"];
    var d = news["media_name"];
    var e = news["url"];
    var f = news["image"];
    var array = [a, b, c, d, e, f];

    var columnA = sheet.getRange(2, 1);
    var valuesA = columnA.getValues();
    var maxid = valuesA[0][0];

    if (a > maxid) {
      sheet.appendRow(array);
    }else{
      break
    }
    sheet.setColumnWidth(6, 120);
    var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
     if (f != null) {
       var cell = sheet.getRange(last_row, 6);
       var image_cell = "=IMAGE(\"" + f + "\", 1)";
       cell.setValue(image_cell);
       sheet.setRowHeight(last_row, 72);
  }else{
    sheet.setRowHeight(last_row, 72);
  }
  }
    sheet.autoResizeColumn(1);
    sheet.sort(1, false);
}
```

This is a complete code. I want to run same function simply to other sheets by using other url.

```
var result= UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.ookami.me/v1/news/public?sport_id=1");
```

"sport_id=1" → "sport_id=2", "sport_id=3"..."sport_id=37".
And

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("soccer");
```

"soccer" → "baseball", "tennis"..."sportsbusiness"(37 sheets).
baseball:2(id), tennis:3..., sportsbusiness:37

And I imagine like this

```
function a () {
    //I don't know the code I want to write 

  function fetch_json ()
}
```

Is it possible?
I don't understand about "dictionary" method, so if there're other ways, plz teach me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get data from different urls and write the data to different sheets in the same spreadsheet based on the sport. I would first define an object for all of the sports:

```
var sportIds = {
  0: 'soccer',
  1: 'baseball',
  2: 'tennis',
  ...
  36: 'sportsbusiness'
};
```

In the above object, the keys are the IDs in your url and the values are the sheet names. Then, you can loop through the object and grab/write the data using something like:

```
var urlBase = "https://api.ookami.me/v1/news/public?sport_id=";
for (var id in sportIds){
  var url = urlBase+id; // Generate the url using the id/key from the object
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sportIds[id]);
  // write to the sheet as desired
}
```

Here, you generate the url using the key in the object and get the sheet you want to write to using the corresponding value. It seems like that should do it. Please comment if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: I could write! Thanks!